# Windows IOT UWP - Relay

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

Good Evening,

I’m doing some troubleshooting on the beginning of my home automation system. I am trying to toggle a relay using a Raspberry PI 3 and Windows IOT in C#. I’ve been playing with the code and I can see the relay toggle once or twice, but then the app crashes. I’m an IOT Noob, so is there something wrong with this code? (Variable names are defined elsewhere and the weird variable names I have below are for my WIP project... I prefer troubleshooting in English)....

```
private void BtnTempFan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BtnTempFan.IsChecked == true)
        {
            TogglePin(TempFan, TempFan_PIN, BtnTempFan, GpioPinValue.High);
        }
        else
        {
            TempFan.Dispose();
        }
    }
    private void TogglePin(GpioPin PinName, int PinNumber, ToggleButton Name, GpioPinValue value)
    {
        int pinnumber = PinNumber;
        GpioPinValue pinvalue;
        var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();
        PinName = gpio.OpenPin(pinnumber);

        if (gpio == null)
        {
            PinName = null;
            LblError.Text = "We can't find the controller on the device" + PinName;
            LblError.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            return;
        }
        if (PinName == null)
        {
            LblError.Text = "We can't find the pin on the device. Pin number " + PinNumber + "does not exist";
            LblError.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            return;
        }
        if (Name.IsChecked == true)
        {
            pinvalue = value;
            PinName.Write(pinvalue);
            PinName.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        }
```

Comment: Two things I see that don't look right but I can't say for sure this is the problem. You are calling ```TempFan.Dispose()``` in the toggle button; meaning when you un-toggle the button it will attempt to use TempFan (however it will be disposed of already.) The other thing is you're calling ```var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();``` and then immediately attempting to assign the pin from it with ```PinName = gpio.OpenPin(pinnumber);``` Afterwards you are then checking ```gpio``` for null.  Check for null immediately after assigning it or assigning PinName will result in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what the exception is. However, I believe you are supposed open a GPIO pin only once per app:

```
var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();
PinName = gpio.OpenPin(pinnumber);
```

You have it in a method which is called once per button click. By opening the pin more than once, you are encountering that the pin is already open, and I believe this is what throws an exception and crashes the app.

---

In my code, I handle pin states in a "driver" class, and have a method called `Connect` which I call once when starting the application. For example:

```
public async Task Connect()
{
    var gpioController = await GpioController.GetDefaultAsync();

    try
    {
        _openPin = gpioController.OpenPin(_doorMotorOpenPin);
        _closePin = gpioController.OpenPin(_doorMotorClosePin);
    }
}
```

This encapsulates the 2 pins: `_openPin` and `_closePin` into a class that I can manage the lifecycle of.

Comment: That could be the answer. I will create that 1x per app method.  It makes a lot of sense in that it currently crashes after the pin toggles once and the relay clicks once. I hope to test it this weekend and finish this thermostat part of the anti-cloud smart home (or so I hope it is).

Answer (score 0):

Codekaizen is correct. I separated out opening the pin into a method that only gets called once and problem solved.

```
private void BtnTempFan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BtnTempFan.IsChecked == false)
        {
            TogglePin(TempFan, TempFan_PIN, BtnTempFan, GpioPinValue.High);
        }
        if (BtnTempFan.IsChecked == true)
        {
            TogglePin(TempFan, TempFan_PIN, BtnTempFan, GpioPinValue.Low);
        }

    }

    private void InitializePins()
    {
        var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();
        //   Show an error if there is no GPIO controller

        if (gpio == null)
        {
            TempFan = null;
            LblError.Text = "We can't find the controller on the device";
            LblError.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            return;
        }

        TempFan = gpio.OpenPin(TempFan_PIN);
        TempFan.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
    }


    private void TogglePin(GpioPin PinName, int PinNumber, ToggleButton Name, GpioPinValue value)
    {
        int pinnumber = PinNumber;
        GpioPinValue pinvalue;
        pinvalue = value;
        PinName.Write(pinvalue);
    }
```